# Python code from Windows to Linux

Tags: python, linux, windows

I have files with code that is formatted for windows. when I try to run them on linux machine i have problem with file encodings. Can anybody suggest a solution for this

on Windows when I run I get -

```
This was return from redis
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "/home/bsingh/python_files/lib/Site.py", line 85, in monitor
self.update1()
File "/home/bsingh/python_files/lib/Site.py", line 78, in update1
for entry in new_pastes[::-1]:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Can you please put your exact error in the question?

Comment: when I do python analyse_tweet.py  It doesnt print anything and goes on a wait. I dont get an error but I also dont get the results

Comment: Why do you think that's a problem with file encodings?

Comment: it appears that the files i have committed are formatted for Windows beacuse on windows machine they work perfectly

Comment: I am not sure if your linux system supports this, but did you do `dos2unix <filename>` ? And are you using `os` in your script? If so, are you doing anything specific to windows?

Comment: no i m not using os in my script

Comment: i havent tried     dos2unix <filename>    i will try it out..thanks

Comment: @ShrutiSrivastava Please provide a minimal working sample of your code in your question, else your question will be flagged to be closed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try -

```
dos2unix <filename>
```

To convert files created in windows to unix format. [Reference](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html)

Please note dos2unix, is ***not python code conversion***, it would convert dos characters to unix equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

if you think this is a problem about file encodings.
maybe you should add

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

or

```
# coding: utf-8
```

in the head(line 1 or line 2) of any python script file.

Comment: I should add this on all the files that I want to run on linux machine ??

Comment: The config just make all you encoding set is fixed to UTF-8