# How to convert turn a python file into a shell script

Tags: python, linux

While running a file entitled `shuf.py` in the linux environment, I run into this following error

```
./shuf.py -e cats and dogs
-bash: ./shuf.py: /usr/bin/python^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

But when i do the same thing as below, it works fine
`python shuf.py -e cats and dogs`

I appended my PATH so that it is correct and the first line of my code is
`#!/usr/bin/python`

I'm not sure what the problem is?

Comment: Looks like your script has the wrong line endings (saved on a windows machine?). You can use `tr` to translate, e.g. `tr -d '\r' < shuf.py > shuf-new.py`

Comment: use the dos2unix command line utility to convert your script

Comment: The tr command makes it work! But i also have to make sure that the code works with Python3, and when i change the first line to 
 #!/usr/bin/python, I get the error that -bash: ./shuf-new.py: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python code from Windows to Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30884008/608639), [How to change end-of-line conventions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41369772/608639), [Python script gives `: No such file or directory`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19764710/608639), etc